# What is the advantage of using a NAT plus private sub-net on AWS vs a public sub-net with locked down security groups and ACL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, networking

My Scenario:
I have an SQS queue with an auto-scaling group of EC2 workers processing messages from the queue into a database in a different region.

Implied Networking Needs for EC2 Workers:

- Access Public Internet to interact with SQS
- Access Public Internet to interact with dB in different region
- Restrict unsolicited inbound traffic because these are not web servers

Networking Options (that I know of):

- Put EC2 Workers in a private subnet with no Elastic IP and allow them to communicate to the internet through a NAT running in a public subnet.
- Put EC2 Workers in a public subnet with public/ elastic? IP addresses. Put them in a restrictive Security Group which prohibits unexpected inbound traffic. Apply a restrictive ACL to the subnet to prohibit unexpected inbound traffic on the subnet level.

I have seen numerous recommendations for using the first approach with the NAT, including within AWS's own documentation. I have not seen any recommendations for the second approach.

NATs seem like an expensive option and can easily turn into a network bottle neck and are a single point of failure. Why is this option recommended so often? Are there disadvantages or deal breakers with the second approach that I'm not aware of?

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/449308/aws-vpc-why-have-a-private-subnet-at-all) is similar but not the same. I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188444/why-do-we-need-private-subnet-in-vpc/22212017#22212017) thread on stack overflow. I have also read the [AWS VPC User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html).

Comment: There is no charge for private IP addresses. Beyond the one public IP address you get per running instance it is $0.005/hour for both addresses not assigned to an instance and addresses assigned to an instance beyond the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many configurations need to share a single public IP.  They need NAT.  Your scenario's network traffic is all internally initiated.  (SQS is polled.)  With this type of traffic, there is no advantage to affording a NAT instance.